# Running python script even if I am not log in

Tags: python, shell, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS EC2 server, and I was wondering about how to keep a python script running even when I am not logged in on the server. I would like to be able to start a long running script and log out. How can I say to the server 'Ok, I will close my laptop now, but you will keep running the script'?

Comment: Technically a question for Unix & Linux or Server Fault or Super User, but I'll answer anyway, because this really is a common question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your script through the `nohup` command. The interface is pretty simple. The call would look something like this:

```
nohup script arg1 arg2
```

Here `script arg1 arg2` are just the usual way you run the script.

When you are able to log back in, `stdout` and `stderr` will be in a file called `nohup.out`. If you want something different, use redirection as described in `man nohup`.